# Need show the position of the stack pointer in ARC Assembly

Tags: assembly, architecture, stack

This is an ARC program that calls the subroutine foo, passing it three arguments, `a`, `b`, and `c`. The subroutine has two local variables, `m` and `n`. I'm trying to understand and show the position of the stack pointer and the contents of the relevant stack elements for a stack based calling convention at the points in the program shown below. Note that subroutine foo does not return anything.

1. just before executing the call at label `x`;
2. when the stack frame for foo is completed;
3. just before executing the ld at label z (i.e., when the calling routine resumes).

   `! Push the arguments a, b, and c
   x:   call foo
   z:   ld %r1, %r2
   .
   .
   .
   foo: ! Subroutine starts here
   .
   .
   y:   jmpl %r15 + 4, %r0`

Any help all be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://mrkay.org/zenpc/ARCHMAN/chapter04.pdf), chapter 4.6 Subroutine Linkage and Stacks
page 138 from "A third calling convention uses a stack" on.

Note that in calls, the stack is not automatically used. You have to push the return
address in the subroutine code. This is somewhat common with RISC architectures.